# FatalErrorException, error in laravel server

Tags: php, laravel, http, controller

today i started server. I set all configure files. make updates etc.. error on my site is on http://46.41.137.45:4563/

ps.its my controller.php .i dont know why its problem.. If anyone could help me I will be grateful. Big Thx guys

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use LRedis;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;

abstract class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    public $user;
    public $redis;
    public $title;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setTitle('Title not stated');
        if(Auth::check())
        {
            $this->user = Auth::user();
            view()->share('u', $this->user);
        }
        $this->redis = LRedis::connection();
        view()->share('steam_status', $this->getSteamStatus());
    }

    public function  __destruct()
    {
        $this->redis->disconnect();
    }

    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
        view()->share('title', $this->title);
    }

    public function getSteamStatus()
    {
        $inventoryStatus = $this->redis->get('steam.inventory.status');
        $communityStatus = $this->redis->get('steam.community.status');

        if($inventoryStatus == 'normal' && $communityStatus == 'normal') return 'good';
        if($inventoryStatus == 'normal' && $communityStatus == 'delayed') return 'normal';
        if($inventoryStatus == 'critical' || $communityStatus == 'critical') return 'bad';
        return 'good';
    }

}
```

Comment: Check your error logs for the full error message. Otherwise you're just guessing in the dark.

Comment: It is telling you that `$this->redis` is `null`... Have you configured your `.env` file ?

Comment: @aynber look at my site... still working and there is the error message..

Comment: @matiaslauriti i think i dont configure .env.. could you give me more info ?

Comment: You are trying to use `redis` but if you didn't set your DB to use `redis`, I think laravel never sets that variable, that's why is `null`

Comment: @matiaslauriti how can i set DB to use redis ? where is config file for that ??

Comment: @matiaslauriti can you help me ?? where i setting it or where i need to use redis...

Comment: @danieldaniellllllo follow this official documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/redis

Comment: @matiaslauriti ok i got it but really i need to use it ??

Comment: @danieldaniellllllo I don't know, you are trying to use it in your code. I don't know why are you trying to do so.

Comment: @matiaslauriti where i can find .env file ?

Answer (score -1):

Set in your `.env` the following variable to `redis` and configure it `.env` too.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
```

To

```
DB_CONNECTION=redis
```